# Tkinter - How to remove the background of a widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

I simply just want to have a button with an image (say an apple) and place it on my window without the background of the button.

Here is some sample code I've rushed:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

testbutton = Button(root, text="If this was an image I should be able to click the image only").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

This makes a button but it has a grey background that a. conflicts with my window background and b. allows users to click the image background.

I'm okay with the solution being windows specific however if there are mac and linux solutions as well i want those too.

I also dont want to use `root.overridedirect(True)` either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the image is a square, then, make the image, the same size as the button. I used this workaround for my GUI application

Comment: Is this the only workaround? My image is an apple so no, it isn't a square.

Comment: Don't know any other, it would help if you could get an apple with a background (making it square)  the color as the background of the button.

Comment: tkinter widgets do not support transparent background.  Try using `Canvas` and `Canvas.create_image()` to simulate a button.

Comment: can you make an example of that please acw1668?

Comment: example [Canvas with clickable image](https://github.com/furas/python-examples/blob/master/tkinter/__canvas__/canvas-click-item/main-image.py) without background.